# Python list (and other objects) change when indexed inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables

My (limited) understanding of Python is that objects defined outside a function should remain the same even if modified inside a function, i.e.

```
def fun():
    i=1
    return('done')

i=0
fun()
i==0 ## True
```

However, lists (and other objects like numpy arrays) change when indexed inside a function:

```
def fun():
    img[0] = img[0] + 100 
    return('done')

img = [0, 1]
fun()
img == [0, 1] ## False
```

Obviously I am missing a core concept with respect to how global and local variables are handled inside functions but can't seem to find any information online.  Could someone please explain why objects change inside functions when indexed?  Also, could someone describe how to avoid this "feature" so that when I index objects (lists, arrays, etc...) within a function, I don't inadvertently change the objects defined outside that function? Thanks!

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. If you pass an object into a function and modify it, you are modifying the same original object. Reassigning a variable (as you do in your first example) is not the same as modifying an object.

Comment: And be sure to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a fuller understanding of how Python works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my recent answer to a closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303154/8431111

There's two concepts in play for your example:

1. behavior of an assignment versus a reference
2. mutating a single container object

For item (1.) when `fun` assigns `i = 1`,
it *creates* a new local variable
due to the lack of a `global` declaration.

For item (2.) let's consider this slightly simpler code instead,
as it doesn't change the essential problem:

```
    img[0] = 100
```

The assignment operator locates `img`
by first consulting the function's local scope (not found)
and then finding it in the module's global scope.
With a reference to the existing `img` object in hand,
it then calls `__setitem__`
to alter what the zero-th element points to.
In this case it will point at an immutable `int` object.
The setter's assignment is performed by a STORE_SUBSCR bytecode instruction.